# Xamarin update ViewModel value when model has changed

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, viewmodel

Let's say there is a model:

```cs
public class MyCustomModel 
{
    public bool parameter { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

and there are also several ViewModels:

```cs
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MyCustomModel model;

    private bool _missingValue = true;
    public bool MissingValue
    {
       get => _missingValue;
       set
       {
           if (_missingValue == value) return;
           _missingValue = value;
           OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MissingValue));
       }
    }
    public MainViewModel(MyCustomModel model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }
}

public class AdvancedViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private MyCustomModel model;

    private bool _missingValue = true;
        public bool MissingValue
        {
            get => _missingValue;
            set
            {
                if (_missingValue == value) return;
                _missingValue = value;
                model.parameter = _missingValue;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MissingValue));
            }
        }

    public AdvancedViewModel(MyCustomModel model) 
    {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

I need to change the value in my MainViewModel when the value changes in AdvancedViewModel (need to call setter). So how to do that properly? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with your approach? Btw, you might think about inheriting from `MyCustomModel` so you don't need to create an instance of `MyCustomModel` in every ViewModel.

Comment: @DennisSchröer it's a good point, I'll implement it, thanks.